# Extracting individual video fields

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows

I need to extract all video *fields* of an interlaced file as individual images.

Is it possible to do this (using ffmpeg or other tools for Windows)?

Comment: What's the source format?

Comment: @Mulvya , DV PAL 720x576i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf field=top top%d.png
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf field=bottom bottom%d.png
```